# Guardar en variables el resultado de una función que se llama varias veces

Tags: python, lista, pandas, funciones

tengo una función que me entrega un df, y necesito concatenar pd.concat([df,df,df,df,df]) todos los resultados entregados por esta función, ejemplo:

```
lista_dv = (['10.164.16.4'],['10.182.16.4'],['10.164.25.1']) # lista de equipos que guardo log
for i, dv in enumerate(lista_dv, start=1): # recorro la lista
    log = conexion_telnet(dev,cmd) # me conecto al dv y obtengo log
    dfx = analisis_log_dev(log) # esta función es donde analizo y creo el df, o sea, esta función me entrega  un dataframe
```

ahora necesito  concatenar todos los " return df " de la función "analisis_log_dev(log)"
o sea, dfx_total = pd.cancat([dfx,...]) o bien como hago para ir guardando los df que me va entregando la función para luego poder trabajar con todos los df generados por dicha función?.

edito: probé la función exec() -> exec (f'df{i}= analisis_log_dev(log)')

si bien veo que crea los df1 /df2 ok desde el explorador de variables (ide spyder), al intentar agregarlos a una lista no me deja lista.append(exec (f'df{i}= analisis_log_dev(log)')), la idea es guardar los resultados de la función para luego realizar un pd.concat(df1,df2,...)

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Comment: Metelos en una lista, creo que también puedes ir concatenación en el for pero no estoy seguro

Comment: hola @Christian,  el tema es que el nombre que entrega la función es siempre el mismo y al meterlo en una lista lista.append(dfx)  lo va pisnado y queda siempre un solo elemento, gracias

Comment: Así no funcionan las listas

Comment: @Christian Tenes razón mala mía, tenia la línea de crear la lista vacía  dentro del bucle for y la vaciaba cada vez que iteraba cada elemento por esto solo me guardaba  la ultima y pensé la pisaba por tener mismo nombre...  ahora creo la lista antes del bucle  for y ya puedo ir guardando los df en la lista... muchas gracias